# How can i optimize this code for a better speed?

Tags: php, database, video, flv

The code:

```
<?php $local_id = $_GET['id'];

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database");
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `videos` WHERE `id` = ".$local_id." ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){$file = $row["file_url"];}

header("Expires: Mon, 20 Dec 1980 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Content-Type: video/flv");

readfile($file); ?>
```

The file is a .flv one but it takes ~ 1 min. to load the video

What can i do to load it faster?

Is this code correct?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point in the current construction. Is the point to get the last row and, if more than 300 rows, the 300th row?

Comment: Please install XDebug and profile the code to see which parts of it take long. Then update your question with your findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use output buffering for transferring large files. php has to store the entire file in memory and wait till it's completely read before giving it out to the client. Just removing the `ob_*` lines should work.

Comment: i removed them but it loads as slow as before

Comment: @m3tsys If you remove the `readfile` line, is it still that slow? If yes, your database is either overloaded or the connection to has a way too high latency. If no: From what medium are you reading, i.e. what file system is `$file` on and what's the throughput of the computer managing that?

Comment: if i remove that line it loads instantly.   I don't really understand the second question.  `$file` it is a .flv file (the bad part is that the file is large ~ 16 MB and this side it can be larger than this depending of the file)  I use the output to display it in jwplayer.

Comment: @m3tsys Well, the transfer runs as following then: `medium (HDD? network?) -> file system/OS -> connection between server and client`. If you can tell me what medium you're using (for starters, a value of `$file` to exclude other than native file protocols) and verify it's not just the low connection speed between server and client, we could further diagnose the problem.

Comment: the file is hosted on another server. A value of `$file` could be `http://dc261.4shared.com/img/598846680/423e3dd8/dlink__2Fdownload_2FWMEIGHDp_2FD_5FBxEKzY_5F9k.mp4_3Ftsid_3D20110515-093046-1651b7d1/preview.flv` If i use this url directly in jwplayer the video loads in ~ 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

First thing i would say is putting an index on the Id field to decrease lookup time... and use memcache to cache DB results
If you don't have constraints on the environment I would put a caching reverse proxy like nginx which caches the HTTP response using your caching headers but will be for every client. Alternatively there are hardware devices that do this for you... usually quite expensive though